# Or Condition in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on entity framework project, i have to apply Or condition in dbContext.Where
I have tried this but its giving me error "Operator || cannot be applied to operand of types lambda expressions"

```
return dataContext.Friends
              .Where((r => r.ToUserId == touserid && r.FromUserId == fromuserid) 
                  || (r => r.ToUserId == fromuserid&& r.FromUserId == touserid ))
              .ToList();
```

I also tried using && instead of || but its giving me same error for &&,how can i apply Or condition for this senario?
I have tried without brackets as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
return dataContext.Friends.Where(r => (r.ToUserId == touserid && r.FromUserId == fromuserid) || (r.ToUserId == fromuserid && r.FromUserId == touserid))
                          .ToList();
```

The only difference is that I deleted the second `r =>` and fixed the parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

Put it into one lambda that includes the `||` instead of `||`ing two separate lambas:

```
return dataContext.Friends.Where(r => (r.ToUserId == touserid && r.FromUserId == fromuserid) || (r.ToUserId == fromuserid&& r.FromUserId == touserid)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

@Syed

```
|| (r => r.ToUserId == fromuserid&& r.FromUserId == touserid )).ToList();
```

Should be

```
|| (r => r.ToUserId == fromuserid && r.FromUserId == touserid )).ToList();
```

note the space between the "fromuserid&&".

Comment: MAnoj, i have spaces in my code,i dont know why it is showing without spaces on posting